# Page with multiple image modals aren't loading images after 1st modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, modal-dialog

I'm running into an issue where I'm creating a page with multiple image modals. When the first image modal is opened, the images within are automatically loaded; when any following image modals are opened, the images do not load until prompted via a javascript button with an onclick action. I would like the first image in each modal to auto-load upon opening every time.

I'm new to image modals and I'm guessing my setup with class and ID names is much clunkier than it needs to be! Any help is appreciated.

My HTML:

```
<!-- MODAL 1 -->

<div id="modal1" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content w3-animate-zoom">

<span onclick="document.getElementById('modal1').style.display='none'" class="button closebtn">&times;</span>
<div class="desc">
<h1>Headline</h1>
<h2>Subheadline</h2>
  <p>Body text</p>
 </div>

<div class="buttons-bar">
<button class="tablink buttons-bar-item button" onclick="openImgtype(event, 'modal1Desktop')">Desktop View</button>
<button class="tablink buttons-bar-item button" onclick="openImgtype(event, 'modal1Mobile')">Mobile View</button>
</div>
<div id="modal1Desktop" class="w3-container imgtype">
<img src="images/paris.jpg">
</div>
<div id="modal1Mobile" class="w3-container imgtype">
<img src="images/nature.jpg" class="mobileview">
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- MODAL 2 -->

<div id="modal2" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content w3-animate-zoom">

<span onclick="document.getElementById('modal2').style.display='none'" class="button closebtn">&times;</span>
<div class="desc">
<h1>Headline</h1>
<h2>Subheadline</h2>
  <p>Body text</p>
 </div>

<div class="buttons-bar">
<button class="tablink buttons-bar-item button" onclick="openImgtype(event, 'modal2Desktop')">Desktop View</button>
<button class="tablink buttons-bar-item button" onclick="openImgtype(event, 'modal2Mobile')">Mobile View</button>
</div>

<div id="modal2Desktop" class="w3-container imgtype">
<img src="images/wedding.jpg">
</div>

<div id="modal2Mobile" class="w3-container imgtype">
<img src="images/falls2.jpg">
</div>

</div>
</div>

<!-- MODAL 3 -->

<div id="modal3" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content w3-animate-zoom">

<span onclick="document.getElementById('modal3').style.display='none'" class="button closebtn">&times;</span>
<div class="desc">
<h1>Headline</h1>
<h2>Subheadline</h2>
  <p>Body text</p>
 </div>

<div class="buttons-bar">
<button class="tablink buttons-bar-item button" onclick="openImgtype(event, 'modal3Desktop')">Desktop View</button>
<button class="tablink buttons-bar-item button" onclick="openImgtype(event, 'modal3Mobile')">Mobile View</button>
</div>

<div id="modal3Desktop" class="w3-container imgtype">
 <img src="images/mountainskies.jpg">
</div>

<div id="modal3Mobile" class="w3-container imgtype">
<img src="images/underwater.jpg" class="mobileview">
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

my Javascript:

```
<script>
document.getElementsByClassName("tablink")[0].click();

function openImgtype(evt, imgtypeName) {
var i, x, tablinks;
x = document.getElementsByClassName("imgtype");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
x[i].style.display = "none";
}
tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
tablinks[i].classList.remove("w3-light-grey");
}
document.getElementById(imgtypeName).style.display = "block";
evt.currentTarget.classList.add("w3-light-grey");
}
</script>
```

my CSS:

```
/* Style the images set on the image grid. */ 

input {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #f6cb19;
}

.myImg {
border-radius: 0px;
cursor: pointer;
transition: 0.3s;
}

.myImg:hover {opacity: 0.3;}

/* Style the hover-over text and colors for the image grid. */

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.container:hover .hovertext{
  opacity: 1;
}

.hovertext {
  text-align: center;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #ee3a38;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  transition: .5s ease;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* Style the images shown within the modules. */

img {width: 100%;
vertical-align:middle;}

button,input,select,textarea{
    font:inherit;
    margin:0
}

button,input{
    overflow:visible
}
button,select{
    text-transform:none
}
button,html [type=button],[type=reset],[type=submit]{
    -webkit-appearance:button
}
 button::-moz-focus-inner, [type=button]::-moz-focus-inner, [type=reset]::-moz-focus-inner, [type=submit]::-moz-focus-inner{
    border-style:none;
    padding:0
}
 button:-moz-focusring, [type=button]:-moz-focusring, [type=reset]:-moz-focusring, [type=submit]:-moz-focusring{
    outline:1px dotted ButtonText
}

.desc 
{padding: 20px;}

.mobileview{
width: 100%; 
max-width: 320px;
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;
display: block;
}

.header {
text-align: center;
padding: 32px;
}

.row {
display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
display: flex;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
flex-wrap: wrap;
padding: 0 4px;
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
}

/* Create four equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
-ms-flex: 33.33%; /* IE10 */
flex: 33.33%;
max-width: 33.33%;
padding: 0 20px;
}

.column input {
margin-top: 40px;
vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
.column {
    -ms-flex: 50%;
    flex: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
}
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.column {
    -ms-flex: 100%;
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
}

/* Modal-specific stuff */

 .modal{
z-index:3;
display:none;
padding-top:100px;
position:fixed;
left:0;
top:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
overflow:auto;
background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7)
}
 .modal-content{
margin:auto;
background-color:#fff;
position:relative;
padding:0;
outline:0;
width: 80%;
max-width:700px;
margin: auto;
box-shadow:0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 4px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19)
}

.w3-animate-zoom {
animation:animatezoom 0.6s;
}

@keyframes animatezoom{
from{
    transform:scale(0)
}
 to{
    transform:scale(1)
}
}

.button:hover{
color:#000!important;
background-color:#ccc!important
}

 .button{
border:none;
display:inline-block;
padding:10px 20px;
vertical-align:middle;
overflow:hidden;
text-decoration:none;
color:inherit;
background-color:inherit;
text-align:center;
cursor:pointer;
white-space:nowrap;
line-height: inherit !important;
-webkit-touch-callout:none;
-webkit-user-select:none;
-khtml-user-select:none;
-moz-user-select:none;
-ms-user-select:none;
user-select:none
}

.button:disabled{
cursor:not-allowed;
opacity:0.3
}

 .closebtn{
color:#fff!important;
background-color:#75bed0!important;
font-size:24px!important;
position:absolute;
right:0;
top:0;
}

.closebtn:hover {
background-color:#4c9baf!important;
}

.buttons-bar .buttons-bar-item{
padding:8px 16px;
float:left;
width:auto;
border:none;
display:block;
outline:0
}

.buttons-bar .w3-dropdown-hover,.buttons-bar .w3-dropdown-click{
position:static;
float:left
}
 .buttons-bar {
white-space:normal
}

 .buttons-bar-block .buttons-bar-item{
width:100%;
display:block;
padding:8px 16px;
text-align:left;
border:none;
white-space:normal;
float:none;
outline:0
}

 .buttons-bar-block.w3-center .buttons-bar-item{
text-align:center
}

.w3-container{
width: 100%;
padding: 20px;
background-color: #F1F1F1;

}

.w3-container:after,.w3-container:before,.w3-panel:after,.w3-panel:before,.w3-row:after,.w3-row:before,.w3-row-padding:after,.w3-row-padding:before, .w3-cell-row:before,.w3-cell-row:after,.w3-clear:after,.w3-clear:before,.buttons-bar:before,.buttons-bar:after{
content:"";
display:table;
clear:both;
}


.w3-light-grey,.w3-hover-light-grey:hover,.w3-light-gray,.w3-hover-light-gray:hover{
color:#000!important;
background-color:#f1f1f1!important
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images in your page are loading correctly. The issue here is that they are hidden.
 In your javascript code, you have the following statement: `document.getElementsByClassName("tablink")[0].click();`
This will invoke the function `openImgtype` with `modal1Desktop` as the secong argument. This will in return set `display: none` on all elements with class `imgtype` except for the one with id `modal1Desktop`. This is why when you open the first modal, the image seem to load correctly. But when you open the other modals, the image seems to be not loaded (it is loaded, issue is that it is still hidden).
I have created a plunker which solves your issue: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/mdNy9BVJox8U7TbOxNsT?p=preview.

Comment: Fantastic! That makes sense. I've implemented it to my working site files and it works like a charm. Thanks so much.